# How can i make and call a method without any paramaters?

Tags: c#, methods

I want to simply call my method like this:
collect.clear;
instead of,
collect.clear();

in other words, I want to make this method

```
    class collect
    {
       public List<string> list = new List<string>();
       public void Clear()
       {
           list.clear();
       }
    }
```

to be called like so

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        collect.clear;
    }
```

is this possible or not at all.

Comment: No you can't do that. You must write `()` when calling a method, otherwise it's a method group.

Comment: the methods aren't set up entirely correctly I was in a hurry sorry.

Comment: Smart getters and setters

Comment: @Train where can I find documentation of these smart getter\setters?

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577591/c-sharp-custom-getter-setter-without-private-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to simply call my method like this: collect.clear; instead of, collect.clear();

Well, frankly: you don't get to decide what the language syntax is, and in C#, the syntax for invoking a method is: `collect.clear();`.

Basically, you can't do what you want. You *could* make it a property, but then you'd need to discard the result (so it can choose between `get` and `set`), i.e. with a *property get* called `clear`, `_ = collect.clear;` - frankly I think that's *a step back* from the `()`. It is also a terrible idea from the basis of unexpected side-effects; most UI elements (including the debugger) and libraries (serializers, etc) think that they can freely evaluate property gets, so it would be very unexpected it reviewing a property had the side effect of clearing the data! Basically, don't do that.

So; embrace the `()`. They express the intent here, for your benefit, the benefit of people reviewing/maintaining it, and for the benefit of the compiler.